# IntelliJ IDE won't start on fresh re-install of 32 bit Linux Mint 18

Tags: java, linux-mint, intellij-idea

I've been running Intellij Community IDEA for many months on my 32 bit Linux Mint (18.0 Sarah) box. IntelliJ had auto-updated a couple of times, it was at build 182.5262.2 when I had to re-install Mint (same version) due to some partitioning probs. Following successful re-install and updates, I re-installed the Intellij build I'd previously been using (182.5262.2). I've tried both versions of this build, i.e with & without JDK, but the IDE will not start with either version. I get the error message "JDK Required: JDK classes seem to be not on IDEA classpath. Please ensure you run the IDE on JDK rather than JRE ".

This is crazy as literally an hour before the re-install I'd been running this exact build of IntelliJ on the same OS, for both Python and Java development. I have tried IntelliJ forum and while they have been very helpful, their suggested solutions (i.e install standalone JRE) didn't work. I can't get past the splash screen before the error is generated.

Many of the offered fixes are reliant on a config dir and it's contents; no such dir exists in my installation. I'm wondering whether my 32 bit cheapskating days are finally at an end. Any suggestions gratefully received.

Java info: (java -version):
openjdk version "1.8.0_222"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_222-8u222-b10-1ubuntu1~16.04.1-b10)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 25.222-b10, mixed mode)
echo $PATH:
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games":JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-i386:/snap/bin
Thanks
PS My other Java dependant application, JMeter, was re-installed and works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to solve this issue although I still don't know exactly how.
I installed a very old version of IntelliJ and tried to start it. It wouldn't start, I got an error message that the JDK version expected was 1.6/1.7 but that my installed version was 1.8.
However, the next time I attempted to start my 2019.2 InteliJ IDE, instead of failing with the message "JDK Required: JDK classes seem to be not on IDEA classpath. Please ensure you run the IDE on JDK rather than JRE", I got the familiar "Do you want to import settings from a previous version?" message. I responded 'No' and from there on I was able to start and configure the IDE and I am now back to where I was, with a fully functional IntelliJ IDE that starts from IDEA.sh